# laravel mail facade queue function sends mail to wrong mailhost

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.8, laravel-mail

I use laravel version 5.8.
To send non-blocking mails through queues I use the mail facade as described in the [documents](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/mail#queueing-mail).
In development I use mailtrap.io to attest the mails are send, in production I use the actual smtp server.
Using the Mail::send method sends the mail through the actual smtp server. Using the Mail::queue method the mail is still send with the mailtrap.io server although I flushed the configuration cache.

The only reference of mailtrap.io in the files I can find is in my development .env file which I don't use in production.

I can't figure out why mail is send to mailtrap.io server using queue instead of to the smtp server as is done using send on the mail facade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it. The threads started with php artisan queue:work keep the old configuration until they are stopped (and restarted).
I have supervisor running on the system to start the threads. I did so when in maintenance mode and with a temporarily development environment. This kept the mailtrap.io reference for the queue.
After stopping and restarting supervisor the threads now use the production environment and thus the right smtp server.